# Struct array not updated, function call returns old values

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, ethereumj

I have created following method in contract with the strcuture

```
contract testContract{
  Student[] public students;

  struct Student{
    string name;
    uint256 age;
  }

  function addStudent(string name, uint256 age){
    students[students.length++] = Student({name:name,age:age});
  }
}
```

now using ethereumj I call the function on the deployed contract as follows:

```
studentContract.callFunction("addStudent","ajay", 15);
Object[] objectArray = studentContract.callConstFunction("students");
```

The object array is of length 2 and contains the values "ajay" and 15, which is fine.

but when I call the function second time as follows :

```
studentContract.callFunction("addStudent","ajay", 15);
Object[] objectArray = studentContract.callConstFunction("students");
studentContract.callFunction("addStudent", "narendra", 17);
objectArray = studentContract.callConstFunction("students");
```

This time the object array should hold 4 values, i.e "ajay",15,"narendra",17.

But it still keeps the older values only, and length is not increased, objectArray has size 2 with values "ajay",15.

Please somebody provide answer to this.

Comment: Did you try calling it with an index? ie. `Object[] objectArray = studentContract.callConstFunction("students", 0);` I don't know how ethereumj works but students is an array.

Comment: Ismael you really made me smile. This worked quite well.

Comment: Solidity can have multiply return values, thus array is here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object[] objectArray = studentContract.callConstFunction("students", index);`

Where index can be any whole number value specifying the index of the items in the student array.

So if you want to access 2nd item on the array, you would require index=1 as the value of index.

Answer on behalf of @Ismael

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

```
students.push(Student({name:name,age:age}));
```

Comment: Where should I write the above code?

Comment: instead of `students[students.length++] = Student({name:name,age:age});`

Comment: should I write it students.push(Student({name:name,age:age})); in place of students[students.length++] = Student({name:name,age:age});

Comment: yes indeed, as said...

Comment: its not working. Please help if you can. Please try the solutions you have suggested at your machine :(. I'm very desperate at this moment.

Comment: @Ronald Kofler you provided new way to push items into arrays so  upvote for you :)